# Convert datetime column to UNIX epoch timestamp using SSIS

Tags: parsing, ssis, datetime-format

I have a column from a CSV that stores datetime. I need to be able to do some simple calculations on the seconds of that datetime field. I want to know how I can convert the datetime field into the UNIX epoch timestamp using a derived column.

In SQL I would usually just do something like this:

```
DATEDIFF(second,{d '1970-01-01'},myDateTime)
```

Which gives me the integer value.

However I've tried the same in SSIS and get errors, why is this not correctly parsing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the SSIS documentation online for [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)? There tends to be usable examples in those docs.